# Salesforce Soap API Login

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

I've made a soap api login call to the saleforce sandbox and everything works fine.
However when I try to move it to the live environment I'm having problems.

**INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.**

Steps I have taken to try and resolve this are:

Generate new enterprise.wsdl

We appended new security token to the password.

Add remote site's ip to trusted ip list in SF.

---

The strange thing is that even though I receive this error from the API, the login history in SF doesn't show the failed login attempts unless I actually type the incorrect username or password.

Could someone please shed some light on this as I have lost hours of my life to it.

Answer (score 3):

I spent the entire day looking for a solution for this same issue. After changing the URL to from Production to Sandbox and then back, I started receiving the same error message.

So I found [this page on their forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008su1IAA) with this line of code:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
```

And everything is working now.

Comment: omg thank you. I just spent the whole afternoon searching for a bug. And that was just due to this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your login calls are still going to https://test.salesforce.com (which is where sandbox logins would go) when it should be going to https://login.salesforce.com for production users. Check your configs.